# Is it possible to test/mock the rpc calls in substrate?

Tags: rpc, testing

I was trying to mock the rpc calls in substrate, but if there's any example for that then I guess it would help better.

Answer (score 1):

You can look here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8bd5510971a8fba46a7b1a6ead8254b9cbf0a73f/client/rpc/src/chain/tests.rs

For example:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn should_return_header() {
    let client = Arc::new(substrate_test_runtime_client::new());
    let api = new_full(client.clone(), test_executor()).into_rpc();

    let res: Header =
        api.call("chain_getHeader", [H256::from(client.genesis_hash())]).await.unwrap();
    assert_eq!(
        res,
        Header {
            parent_hash: H256::from_low_u64_be(0),
            number: 0,
            state_root: res.state_root,
            extrinsics_root: "03170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c111314"
                .parse()
                .unwrap(),
            digest: Default::default(),
        }
    );

    let res: Header = api.call("chain_getHeader", EmptyParams::new()).await.unwrap();
    assert_eq!(
        res,
        Header {
            parent_hash: H256::from_low_u64_be(0),
            number: 0,
            state_root: res.state_root,
            extrinsics_root: "03170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c111314"
                .parse()
                .unwrap(),
            digest: Default::default(),
        }
    );

    assert_matches!(
        api.call::<_, Option<Header>>("chain_getHeader", [H256::from_low_u64_be(5)])
            .await
            .unwrap(),
        None
    );
}
```

There are different test setups for RPC. You can poke around in the substrate/client/rpc/src folder:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/8bd5510971a8fba46a7b1a6ead8254b9cbf0a73f/client/rpc/src

Comment: I will take a look here. Thanks